# Apollo4 and GraphQL CORS

Tags: graphql, cors, apollo-server

I'm trying to access my graphQL server on my production server but getting the CORS error.

The request url is: `https://mov****.at/graphql`

In my `index.mjs` where I start the Apollo server I have CORS defined as so:

```js
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  cors({ origin: ['https://mov***.at', 'https://mov***.at/graphql', 'https://studio.apollographql.com'] }),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server),
);
```

And in my `graphql.module.ts` I have the uri defined like so `const uri = 'https://mov***.at/graphql';`

I've read > https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/cors/#configuring-cors-options-for-apollo-server but I'm not resolving the issue.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader

Comment: What CORS error?

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader

Comment: Please post the full error message from **the browser's console**.

Comment: The console doesn't show the error, it's a http request error. But the console shows: `ERROR ApolloError: Http failure response for https://mov***.at/graphql: 0 Unknown Error`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue, I've resolved it by configuring my nginx server block to accept CORS:

```
upstream mov***at_upstream_config {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

upstream mov***at_upstream_graphql_config {
    server 127.0.0.1:4100;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mov***.at/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mov***.at/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  server_name www.mov***.at;
  root /root/angular-mov***at/dist/angular-mov***at/browser;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri @ssr;
  }

  location @ssr {
    proxy_pass http://mov***at_upstream_config;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location /graphql {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_pass http://mov***at_upstream_graphql_config;  # Proxy to your GraphQL server
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mov***.at;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri?;
}
```

I also don't need to specify any CORS configuration in my Apollo server file

```js
app.use(
  cors(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server),
);
```

Don't forget to restart nginx after changing the server block